# Create a trigger to update time stamp on inserted or updated records?

Tags: plsql

I am trying to create an Oracle trigger that would update `entry_stamp` column (type=`DATE`) on every inserted or updated record for a certain table. Here is my script:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER mytable_entry_stamp 
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON mytable FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN :NEW.entry_stamp := SYSDATE; END;
```

I am getting this error:

> ORA-04084: cannot change NEW values for this trigger type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Oracle/PLSQL: AFTER UPDATE Trigger](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/triggers/after_update.php):

- You can not update the :NEW values.
- You can not update the :OLD values.

It appears that Oracle cannot update a record inside `AFTER` trigger, unlike MSSQL. So it is reserved for logging/audit purposes, i.e. a record can be inserted or updated **in another table**. After I converted this trigger to `BEFORE`, it worked flawlessly.